# deleting data from multiple mysql tables using python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to delete some rows from almost 500 tables in mysql database using python.

I know that the query should be something like this:
DELETE FROM (table name)
[WHERE conditions] [ORDER BY ...] [LIMIT rows]

but I am not sure what should I use for the table name when I looping over the tables!

here is my loop

```
from mysql.connector import (connection)
# call databasecnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='user', password='PW',host='127.0.0.1', database= 'database')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'options_20%'")
table_names = [tables for (tables, ) in cursor]
for t in table_names:
cursor.execute("Delete table-refs WHERE Expiration = Datadate AND UnderlyingSymbol = 'SPY'")
cnx.commit()
```

I got an error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that...etc

Answer (score 0):

Test with this.... You did'nt put `from` on your query statement.

```
for table in table_names:
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM"+ table +"WHERE Expiration = Datadate AND UnderlyingSymbol = 'SPY'")
```

Comment: yes, it was copying mistake. still error in  SQL syntax :(

Comment: Add a space before and after  *table* concatenation. Better yet use `str.format` with MySQL backticks to escape special chars and spaces: ``"DELETE `{}` WHERE Expiration = Datadate AND UnderlyingSymbol = 'SPY'".format(table)``

Comment: I just solve the problem and it works now perfectly. Thank you all

Comment: You should have to explain what you did for solve the problem, for help others with the same problem.